# Getting Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android

i've created a service in android in which at every 3 seconds it will send the GPS cordinates to a remote mysql database.

but i did the 3 seconds loop using ScheduledExecutorService but when i click the start button to start the service i'm getting  `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

```
 @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Application Started!!!...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

            // This schedule a runnable task every 2 minutes
            scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                updateLatLong();
              }
            }, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            return START_STICKY;
        }
```

Comment: just a further comment to my answer below - I've found on many devices that the GPS granularity is often about 20seconds or more. You may find that 3seconds is too short.

Comment: please add your updateLatLong code

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, this error relates the the way you are trying to access a Handler from the wrong thread.

Remember your `Service.onStartCommand()` method is running on the main thread.

Your `ScheduledExecutorService` is not running on the main thread.

Depending on what the `updateLatLong()` method is doing, you need to run part of that on the main thread - I'm guessing there might be some UI changes you make, or perhaps making a callback to the Service or Activity from that method.

So put that callback or UI code in a `runOnUiThread()` block... that will ensure that you are on the UI thread when you start, and on the UI thread when complete.

---

There are alternatives, such as using `ASyncTask` or an `IntentService` but the above is the essence of the problem.